# Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub menu missing in Eclipse webapp project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

The menu in the title is missing.

[image: Missing option]

I created a Maven webapp project as instructed in my book, and my book is now saying generate a web.xml by right-clicking on the project , Java EE Tools -> Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub , but that submenu is missing.

I have checked project facets and Dynamic Web Module is checked, with version no. 2.3.
[image: Project Facets settings]

Do I need to convert this Maven webapp project to a Dynamic Web project? It seems a Maven webapp project is somehow not a Java EE project. Is that correct?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: I have checked a lot of similar questions but have not been able to find an answer to this apparently trivial problem.

Edit: FWIW there is some information about conflicts in the Project Facets window:

[image: Conflict information]

Comment: What perspective do you have open in eclipse?

Comment: I have the Java EE perspective open.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The things I did to solve this were:

1, edit `[projectname]\.settings\org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml`. I changed the `"jst.web"` version to `4.0`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <runtime name="Apache Tomcat v9.0"/>
  <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="4.0"/>
  <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
  <installed facet="java" version="1.8"/>
  <installed facet="jst.jsf" version="2.2"/>
</faceted-project>
```

2, tried the usual, F5, Project Clean.., Maven->Update Project, etc to no avail.

3, restarted eclipse, to no avail

4, noticed there was now a WEB-INF/web.xml but it needed editing to bring it into line with the dynamic web module version (4), so I changed it to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

5, F5, Project Clean.., Maven->Update Project, "mvn clean install" and it seems eclipse is happy.